# Extract patterned text from a string with Hive

Tags: sql, hive, regexp-replace

I have data in a column that looks like this:

> - Countryside_Video_-_A18-49_Pub_-*Q3*-_Flight_7_18_49_BOTH
> - Countryside Video - M18-25 Validated -Q4 - Flight 1
> - PremiumBrand_2019_Upfront_Video_-_W18-49_Validated_-_Q4_Flight_1_18_49_FEMALE
> - Travel Around the World - W25-54 Validated - Q3 25-54_FEMALE

I need to extract the age and gender value from each string:

> - A18-49
> - M18-25
> - W18-49
> - W25-54

It's tricky, because there could be any number of combinations between the letters A,M,F and a number range. The letters signify Age, Male, or Female. The number range is the age range.

From some googling, it looks like I might be able to use a regexp_extract function, but I'm a novice to Hive. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try generic way to find and match the records

select * , regexp_extract(id1, '([A-Z]+[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2})', 1) from temp3;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Hive on hand to test, but this might work:

```
select regexp_extract(col, '([AMW][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2})', 1)
```